HDF5 CXX package cannot be detected by cmake when installing it alongside petsc
I installed PETSc alongside hdf5, and would like to utilize #include <H5Cpp.h>. Examining the installation directory, we find this file in
/petsc/linux-gnu/externalpackages/hdf5-1.12.1/c++/src/H5Cpp.h

This directory apparently provides the uncompiled source code, so we can include this dir to access the .h file but don't have any lib directory to subsequently link to so the methods can actually be found. PETSc was configured with the --download-hdf5 option.
Is there anything that can be done to access the CXX HDF5 functionalities without having to rely on any external hdf5 installations?
